# how to switch ContentPage to another ContentPage

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I Have One Page That is "Category", if you select one, are going to "SubCategories" of that selected category, and finnaly if you select one Sub, needs to switch to anoter ContetPage which is not in the context of categories, that is, I have to kill the category and subcategory screen and trigger the other screen that I need

I Tried it

```
void OnItemTapped(Object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataItem = (SubCategoria)(e.Item);

        App.TodosOutrosFiltros.IdSubCategoria = dataItem.IdSubCategoria;

        _navigationService.PopModalAsync();
    }
```

but he just went back to the category, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the root if your "Category" is the root

```
_navigationService.PopToRootAsync();
```

Or you can remove the pages you want like this:

```
this.Navigation.RemovePage (this.Navigation.NavigationStack [this.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
```

this will remove the number of pages that you want from the stack, and then you can "Pop" like you are doing